# disable default na parsing in pandas read_csv only for specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to read a csv file as pandas dataframe but keep certain column exactly as it is without filling in NaN.

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

main_ts_str = """key,dt,value
5013,2020-06-19,NULL
NA,2020-06-18,25.5
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(main_ts_str))
```

This code will give me the following

```
      key          dt  value
0  5013.0  2020-06-19    NaN
1     NaN  2020-06-18   25.5
```

What I want is for the 'key' column to keep the original value while let the 'value' column be filled with NaN. (Something like the dataframe below)

```
    key          dt value
0  5013  2020-06-19   NaN
1    NA  2020-06-18  25.5
```

I know I can disable the NA parsing by setting `keep_default_na` but this will disable na parsing for all columns.

There is also a way to use `na_values` to specify column specific NA strings. But my issue is I have many of these 'value' columns that I do not know their column names ahead of time. The only thing I know before I read in the file is the file has a 'key' column and I want to load anything in this column as it is.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `converters` parameter from [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and pass a dictionary for converting values only in certain columns (`key` column in this specific example).

```py
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(main_ts_str), converters={'key':str})
```

```py
print(df)
    key          dt  value
0  5013  2020-06-19    NaN
1    NA  2020-06-18   25.5
```

```py
print(df.info())
...
 0   key     2 non-null      object
 1   dt      2 non-null      object
 2   value   1 non-null      float64
```